# Rails 5.1 add a specific column as foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, foreign-keys, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a issue with foreign keys.
I have 3 tables : Users, Members and Groups.
Basically I want the user to be able to create groups. The user provide a name, a description and on create a token is generated. Then other users can join this group via the members table. The members table has user_id and group_id. User can join the group providing the group_id which is not very cool, instead I would like the users to join the group providing the token.
Everything is working except the fact that they can join with the token. My question is how can I use the token instead of the group_id ?

I already tried to add foreign keys like this but nothing is going on in the schema :

```
add_foreign_key :members, :groups, column: :group_id, primary_key: :auth_token

add_foreign_key :members, :groups, column: :auth_token, primary_key: :auth_token
```

I also tried to add foreign key in my model :

```
belongs_to :group, foreign_key: "group_auth_token"

has_many :members, foreign_key: "group_auth_token", class_name: "Group"
```

Here are my actual models in case :

Group.rb

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
has_secure_token :auth_token

    has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :users, :through => :members

end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

    has_secure_password

  has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :groups, :through => :members
end
```

Member.rb

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group

  validates :user_id, :presence => true
  validates :group_id, :presence => true
  validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:user_id, :group_id]}

end
```

I'm really confused with all this, I'm pretty sure the answer is obvious but I'm just lost, anybody to help me out ?
Thanks

EDIT : It looks like it's not clear enough so I'm adding a few things. When the user create the group this is what's happening in my controller :

```
def create
    @group = Group.new group_params
    @group.owner_id = current_user.id if current_user
    if @group.save
      @user = current_user.id if current_user
      Member.create(group_id: "#{@group.id}", user_id: "#{@user}")
      flash[:success] = "The Group has been created."
      redirect_to group_path(@group)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

The Member.create is to add the User automatically in the group. If anybody want's to join a group this is what is going on in my member controller :

```
def create
        @member = Member.new member_params
        @member.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
        if @member.save
            flash[:success] = "You Joined the Group."
            redirect_to mygroups_path
        else
            flash.now[:error] = "Something went wrong. Are you in the group already ?"
            render 'new'
        end
    end
```

And of course there is a form to create a new member (join the group) where the user provide the group_id (`member_params`) in the controller.

I want to be able to use the token instead of the group_id.

EDIT 2 :

So I have a error with your code jvillian. I paste it in the MembersController. In my form I changed the :group_id by :auth_token and this is my form :

```
<%= form_for @member do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :auth_token %>
    <%= f.text_field :auth_token %>
    <%= f.submit "Join the Group" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What do you mean 'join the group providing the token'? Do you mean in the UI? If so, the UI and the mechanics of record association are largely unrelated. Look up group by token then associate as normal. Or, am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes in the UI. Once the group is created the other users can join the group by creating a record in the members table. I did a form where the user provide the group_id and the user_id come from the current user in the controller so they don't have to give it in the form. Instead of this group_id I want the user to be able to use the token. What do you mean by largely unrelated ?

Comment: If you add to your question the (presumably controller) code where you are associating the user with the group, then I can show you what I mean.

Comment: I just edited the post

Comment: Posted answer. Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code may not be *exactly* correct, but it should be in the right direction.

```
def create
  if @group = Group.find_by(auth_token: params[:auth_token]) && current_user
    if @group.users << current_user
      flash[:success] = "You Joined the Group."
      redirect_to mygroups_path
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Something went wrong. Are you in the group already ?"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

I put in:

```
params[:token]
```

Naturally, that may not be quite right. Adjust to fit your own params.

This bit:

```
if @group.users << current_user
```

may not be correct as I forget what the shovel operator returns. But, you can look that up in [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference).

**TO CORRECT YOUR FORM**

Presumably, you're doing something like:

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @member = Member.new
  end

  ...

end
```

So, when you do this:

```
<%= form_for @member do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :auth_token %>
  <%= f.text_field :auth_token %>
  <%= f.submit "Join the Group" %>
<% end %>
```

`form_for` can access your `@member` instance.

BUT, when you do this:

```
<%= f.text_field :auth_token %>
```

You're getting an error because `form_for` is trying to access the `.auth_token` attribute on `@member` which, naturally, doesn't exist. But remember, all you're trying to do here is submit a form that has a token. So, instead, do something like:

```
<%= form_for @member do |f| %>
  <%= label_tag 'auth_token', 'Token' %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'auth_token' %>
  <%= f.submit "Join the Group" %>
<% end %>
```

In this way, the `auth_token` field is no longer directly derived from `@member` and you're no longer trying to access a non-existent method on `@member`.

Your params will look something like:

```
Parameters: {"auth_token"=>"whatever the user entered"}
```

If you want the `auth_token` to be nested inside `group`, like this:

```
Parameters: {"group"=>{"auth_token"=>"whatever the user entered"}}
```

Then do:

```
<%= form_for @member do |f| %>
  <%= label_tag 'group[auth_token]', 'Token' %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'group[auth_token]' %>
  <%= f.submit "Join the Group" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have `undefined method `auth_token' for #<Member:0xf457860>` I guess my relations are not well in place. What is correct in what I wrote regarding the relations ? Because I tried several things but it is not working so far. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I don't know where that error is occurring. You could edit your original question and add your stack trace (from your console).

Comment: Naturally. This has nothing to do with your original question. You're mis-using your form builder given what you're trying to do. You should start a new question where you show your form erb (or haml or slim or whatever). I'll look for it. After we fix that, you can come back and accept this answer.

Comment: I posted my form on the main topic, as it is related to the same question. I'm not a beast in rails obviously but I'm willing to learn. Maybe I did a stupid mistake or I don't understand something... I'm sorry but I try my best

Comment: This really isn't related to your original question, because your original question was about foreign keys (which was all wrong to begin with). But, I added the answer anyway. You owe me a baguette.

Comment: Thank you very much for that, to be honest I would'nt have find this on my own, but it's also well explained so you teached me something, and for that thank you very much ! It goes further in the controller as the auth_token and the current user is found thanks to the form, but I have this as a error : `Member(#75419256) expected, got #<User id: 1.....ALL THE USER DETAIL..... which is an instance of User(#97239624)`.I will go through the doc you provided to check where the problem is coming from. Thanks for everything.

Comment: My bad. It should be `@group.users << current_user`, not `@groups.members << current_user`.

Comment: The problem is coming from here `if @group.members << current_user`, it looks like the current_user can't be added in there. Probably because I messed up with my DB and this relations thing... Well I will look for that on my own I don't want to bother you will every each problems I encounter. Thank you very much, I appreciate the help

Comment: I have this error with your new code : 'undefined method `users' for #<User:0x67913d0>`. EDIT : Funny.. I do it in the console and it works ^^

Comment: I modified the code a bit, I don't know why it worked in console and not on the page but I managed something like this : I removed `&& current_user` and I added this on the next line : `@user = current_user if current_user` and it works. I don't know if it's the best but it is working